# How to pass PHP variable value to jquery function?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i have this JQuery Script in Wordpress /js folder and i need to change some values that i store in the Database.

```
$( "#slider-range2" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 18,
    max: 90,
    values: [ 35, 50 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "-" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }
});
$( "#amount2" ).val( $( "#slider-range2" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + "-" + $( "#slider-range2" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

The Jquery documentation is not clear to me.
Values that i need to change are [35 , 50]. These values ​​are stored in the database.
How can i do this from the js file? How can i pass a PHP variable value to jquery function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to keep the external js file and not embed it into your php script, have php write out two global js vars, and modify the js file to use those instead.

e.g. in php:

```
echo "<script>var val1 = $var1; var val2 = $var2;</script>";
```

and in your js file:

```
values: [val1, val2]
```

---

But if you can change your js file to be a php file instead, you can do something like:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/javascript'); ?>
... // your regular js code  here
values: <?php echo $var1 ?> , <?php echo $var2 ?>
...
```

Now, you can use on your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js.php">
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. My only alteration would be to change the JS variables from `val1` and `val2` to something much more specific, like `slider_range2_val1` (and `2`), to minimize the risk of accidentally overwriting them elsewhere in the JS code.

Comment: Better yet, put them in a module, just like you would with a class.  You could have the PHP code generate an object called `mymodule.config` containing a `slider_values` property, as well as any other configurable properties you need.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say you just do it like this:

```
$( "#slider-range2" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 18,
    max: 90,
    values: [ <?php echo $value1; ?>, <?php echo $value2; ?> ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "-" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
  }
```

});

where of course $value1 and $value2 are the values you get from the database.

-edit- or what the other guy said, you can use a php for loop to make the size of your array dynamic that way :)

Comment: @alejoabella  Of course you can, just change the file extension.

Comment: maybe then you could also consider creating a php web method and call that from your jquery code?

Comment: @mblase75 completely forgot that the browser is not concerned about the extension. However doesn't it not cache the file like a normal js but the php is dynamic?

Comment: @alejoabella: You can only run PHP code in a PHP document. The only other option I can think of is to set the values as a global JS variable in the top of your PHP/HTML document.

Comment: @mblase75 And that's a better way to do it, because it leaves the majority of the JS code in a static file, which can be cached.  Running the script itself through the PHP interpreter means it has to be regenerated and redownloaded every time.

Comment: @Wyzard: Well, it might be better PHP, but it's considered bad JavaScript. :-) (Personally, I don't understand why OP's entire code sample is in an external file to begin with, but I'm sure he has his reasons.)

Comment: @mblase75, how's it "bad JavaScript" to keep your code in a static file?  That's how most JavaScript libraries are distributed, and how they're meant to be used.  It makes sense to generate code dynamically if the actual sequence of statements needs to vary, but not if you just need to change a few integers.

Comment: @Wyzard: Using global variables to store JS data is considered bad practice, because those variables might accidentally be overwritten by other code. The best compromise would be for OP to include that short block of sample code in his PHP/HTML file and externalize the rest.

Comment: @mblase75, naturally you wouldn't just dump a bunch of arbitrary variables in global scope; you'd follow the same naming conventions that are used for modules and classes.  The range values for the slider in this question could be something like `mymodule.config.slider_range.min` and `mymodule.config.slider_range.max`, where `mymodule.config` is the object that's dynamically generated by PHP code.

Comment: (Oops, make that `mymodule.config.slider_values` — I was thinking they represented a min and max, but those are specified separately.)

Answer (score 4):

PHP code runs on the server and jQuery code runs in the browser, so you can't directly pass PHP variables to jQuery functions because you can't directly *call* jQuery functions from PHP code.

What you need to do is make the PHP code generate JavaScript code that, when it runs later in the browser, will set some JavaScript variables to the values you want.  For example, you could make the PHP code generate a `<script>` element in the page's header that contains JavaScript assignment statements, and then modify your `.js` file so that instead of the numbers 35 and 50, it refers to those variables.

You can also put PHP code in your `.js` file itself, as other answers have suggested, but only if it's actually a PHP script rather than a static file.  My recommendation would be to keep the majority of the JavaScript code in static files (so that browsers can cache them) and have the PHP just generate assignments for a few global variables that the rest of the scripts can refer to.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could make an ajax request to the server before you define your slider.

eg.
   var myValues = function(){ 
      //do ajax call to php script that returns values
      return value};

```
$( "#slider-range2" ).slider({     
   range: true,     
   min: 18,
   max: 90,
   values: myValues(),
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "-" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
   } 
}); 
$( "#amount2" ).val( $( "#slider-range2" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + "-" + $( "#slider-range2" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Just echo it out, like this.

```
$( "#slider-range2" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 18,
    max: 90,
    values: <?php echo $your_variable ?> ,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "-" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the value. If it's a simple numeric value, you can just echo it. If it's complex or a string, you might echo it in JSON format via [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (since [JSON](http://json.org) is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax), since that will handle escaping and such for you.

Note in both cases that the PHP is happening *on the server* as the page request is satisfied, and JavaScript is using it *later* on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite tricks is naming your javascript file somename.js.php and then sending a javascript header:

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```

Now, you can use full php functionality (including db calls) inside your javascript.

However, you'll want to ensure that you're properly caching your file with the server, so it's not downloaded on every page.  Something like:

```
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 2012 05:00:00 GMT")
```

As a rule of thumb, I generally keep any changing JS variables in the main php file, and pass them to functions declared in an external JS file.